Understanding the explanation of [..] from the Rust docs
I have some code like:
let signer_seeds = [&seeds[..]];

seeds is a nested list of u8 (ie, some bytes)
The Rust docs for operators state

expr[..], expr[a..], expr[..b], expr[a..b]
Collection indexing pretending to be collection slicing, using Range, RangeFrom, RangeTo, or RangeFull as the “index”

So expr[..] is "Collection indexing pretending to be collection slicing, using Range" I don't understand this explanation. Is Rust doing some kind of destructuring on seeds here?

There is no kind of destructuring, you're creating a 1-element array, whose sole element is a slice reference.

“Collection indexing pretending to be collection slicing” — Rust has no slicing. It only has indexing (subscripting). But since you can implement indexing on your type separately for each type of the index key, you can get something that looks like slicing by indexing with keys that look like slices. This differs from, say, Python, where L[a:b] is syntactic sugar, and there is no such object as a:b (internally, a slice object is constructed). But in Rust, a..b is an object in its own right.

@Masklinn thanks. Can I clarify if you are stating the outer brackets create a 1-element array (which I already understand), or the [..]? My question is about the [..].

The brackets are a indexing operator, the .. is a RangeFull literal.

@mikemaccana that's just a slice for the entire collection. So it's creating a slice of the entirety of seeds whatever that is.

Thanks @IvanC for your comment, that answers my question. I found https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/struct.RangeFull.html to get more info about RangeFull. Do you want to add that as an answer?

@BallpointBen "Rust has no slicing" is probably too reductionist. It has slicing, implemented by way of an Index implementation in the core library, as you explain. (If you remove core from Rust then I guess, yes, it doesn't have slicing.) If we go down this path we can say that Rust "doesn't have" a lot of things that core and std do give us. (Also nitpick: a..b is a value, not an object.)
